# Is there a gem that provides read/write/delete actions for wide range of URI schemes, such as file://, env://, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, uri, open-uri

I am the author of a ruby gem `sym` which performs symmetric encryption.

As part of the command line interface, I would very much like to be able to consume the data to [de]encrypt, and write the result out via a pluggable set of URIs. It seems to me that we are already using URIs in this way, for example `file://` exists and is supported by `OpenURI` module.

However, what I would like is a gem that not only understands much wider set of URIs but can also read/write and possibly delete resources defined via URIs.

This functionality could be so tremendously useful because any ruby program that reads and writes data can suddenly replace `File.read` with, something completely generic:

```
var_value = SuperURI.parse('env://BASH_VARIABLE_NAME')`.read
```

or

```
redis_op = SuperURI.write('redis://localhost:6379/1/OP,Arg1,Arg2')
```

or

```
contents = SuperURI.parse('scp://user@host/path/file').read
```

As I continued on this path, I've thought of the following candidate URIs. **Not all of them can support writing or deleting the resource, but all of them can read the data.**

Existing URIs supported by OpenURI:

```
http[s]://user@host/path/file    
file://filename                  
ftp[s]://user@host/path/file
ldap://ldap.example.com/dc=example?
```

Suggested possible ways of accessing local and remote data:

```
string://value                   
env://variable
std[in|out]://                         
shell://command                  
keychain://item_name                  
redis://127.0.0.1:6397/1/OP,arg1,arg2,...   
memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/OP,arg1,arg2
scp://user@host/path/file        
postgresql://user@host/db/?sql=select%20now
```

And so on.

What are people's thoughts on usefulness of this gem (let's just call it `SuperURI` for now) which would provide implementations for the unconventional URI protocols?

Is it useful? Is it a horrible idea? Is it inherently insecure?

Thoughtful opinions from the Ruby community are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a little open-ended for the Stack Overflow format, it's probably a better fit with [`/r/programming`](http://reddit.com/r/programming), [Quora](http://quora.com) or even a Ruby-specific chat room. Although that's an interesting idea, I'd hope that any write operations are undertaken only with deliberate intent on the part of the user and are never done in an automagical way that might lead to ugly surprises.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the pointers. I certainly find myself on SO much more often than I find myself on Quora or Reddit — hence my first choice was to post it here.

Comment: GitHub issue + announcement on social media as a "Request for Comments" is not a bad idea either. It's an interesting concept for a library. I'd try and pivot from the "URI" name which implies a parser and towards something more "File System" oriented so it's clear that this is a read/write mechanism.

Comment: I started the gem `uri-IO` here: https://github.com/kigster/uri-io

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, so start writing.

You seem to have a good idea of what the gem should do and how it should behave. As you have already created a gem, I presume you have the requisite skills necessary to create another.

I'd suggest that there are already gems (and standard libraries) that handle particular actions (`File` for file handling for example). So the new gem should just parse the input string and pass the result on to the relevant existing library/gem.

I'd also suggest that rather than having `parse('string').read` you just use `read('string')`. It maybe good to try and support the CRUD actions; so:

- `SuperURI.create('file://filename', data)`
- `SuperURI.read('file://filename')`
- `SuperURI.update('file://filename', data)`
- `SuperURI.delete('file://filename')`

I've just thrown together [some code](https://github.com/reggieb/super_uri) showing how I'd do it. Feel free to abuse it at will.

Comment: Thank you for that! The reason I chose `parse` is consistency with the `URI` module and it's intentions. As most of the concrete implementations of various URI schemes subclass `GenericURI`, it felt right to reuse their API.